# semi-space or half-space in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

how to type semi-space or half-space in android studio XML files (values->strings,layouts) and java files.

CTRL+SHIFT+2 not working .

می‌باشد 
to 
می باشد

Comment: use Unicede character code. Choose space which you need from here: http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html You likely want `U+2009`

Comment: This issue should be fixed since 2017.3 builds of IntelliJ-based tools: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177979 . What version do you run?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Android Studio (Java and XML), we must use this method to write semi-space. \u200c

For instance: این متن تست می\u200cباشد

Output: این متن تست می‌باشد

Answer (score 11):

change your keyboard to Persian(fa,فا) and try this shortcut key

alt+0157

for Example: میباشد

Output: می‌باشد

Comment: Thanks, the accepted answer has a very short space, I'd to put around 15 successive space to have that work. Your answer works great. the unicode representation of `alt + 0157` is `\u009D`

Answer (score 4):

i write my text in notepad with semi-space (CTRL+SHIFT+2) then copy that to Android Studio.

Comment: not worked in MacBook.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Persian standard keyboard and add semi-space by SHIFT+SPACE

Comment: If Shift + Space didn't work use Shift + B. It's the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can add shortcut text in Android Studio.
Like this:
lorem   ->Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris....

Answer (score 1):

You must change your keyboard to Persian (standard). you can do it in the following way

Start > Settings > Time & Language > Language then under Preferred languages click on your language (in this case Persian) after that click on the option button and then pick Persian (standard) keyboard. after you did that you can use half-space with Shift + Space in webStorm or any other programs